# Kony Mobile Fabric Cloud - DB

Tags: temenos-quantum

When i buy Kony Mobile Fabric (Cloud version), will i get a data source like my SQL or it provides me the space to install my SQL database to save form data? I have read from documentation which appears to say that Data Storage is available.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Kony Mobile Fabric can now be use free, with no charge/subscription/licence at manage.kony.com for your test/perso app.

And, you can use Eclipse For Java dev to code your web services that forge T-SQL request before sending them to your SQL Server for execution, and return the results to the app.

Answer (score 0):

Kony Cloud MF provides various adapters through which you can connect your databases or web services. There is an something called object services using which you can store some data but bit complex. But I don't recommend using object services if you have more data to store. As far as I know, there is no option to install db on cloud MF.

Instead you can think of creating free db in clouds like Amazon AWS and use the Kony MF adapter to connect with it.

Hope it helps!